# I want to know how to traverse all keys with ShardedJedis in Jedis?

Tags: java, redis, reverse, jedis

I am writing a message pull center on the sever side with redis, `MsgEntity` is javabean to represent a message:
package com.pipeline;

public class MsgEntity {

```
private String msgId;

private String content;

private int expire ;

public String getMsgId() {
    return msgId;
}

public void setMsgId(String msgId) {
    this.msgId = msgId;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public int getExpire() {
    return expire;
}

public void setExpire(int expire) {
    this.expire = expire;
}
```

}

I need to store a message entity as hash structure in redis, the key is `msgId`, my demand is traverse all message in redis, I use `ShardedJedis` in java to guarantee performance, so unlike `Jedis`, there is no `keys` mothod for me to get all keys in redis, is there any way to fix this?

Maybe `List` is helpful, but since `expire` time exists, and no way to set an item's expire time in `List`, I don't think it really helpful.
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

see [issues#149](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/149)

The author explained it.